# How to not allow user to skip video

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Is there a way to let the user watch a video  without skipping any part? Basically something along the lines, where they have to watch the entire video to go to the next process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 video player prevent seeking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001635/html5-video-player-prevent-seeking)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

Long answer: All you can do is hiding the controls or using other analytical methods to determine whether a skip has occurred. But at the end, keep in mind that your code depends on a client side interpreter. If a user really wants to skip it, there will always be a way to do it.